# Software similar to WinRAR?

Tags: 18.04, mate

is there any software very similar to WinRAR that is for linux? in specific for ubuntu 18.04 mate, preferably having a visual interface or contextual menu when you right click on a .rar, thanks, I'm new to linux

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried file roller ? It's installed by default in Ubuntu (not sure about Ubuntu Mate, so.....)   ; It's a graphical tool for extracting and compacting files and works by right clicking ,just as winrar in windows.

Try searching for it in the store , or install synaptic package manager and search for "file-roller" (without quote marks). I also recommend you to install the "unrar" package found in synaptic , non-free version. 
If you can't find the app store in your system, you can install synaptic by typing in the terminal:

sudo apt install synaptic

It then will ask your password, you can type it normally and hit enter when you done.
After, search for synaptic in the system menu and follow the steps

Comment: yes, i have that tool on my right click, i download unrar from "sudo apt install unrar" and now, the tool supports files rar